Unity - How to always show status bar and navigation bar on android app
I was able to display the status bar and make it Transparent using UnityTransparentStatusBarTheme on the xml but my app goes from behind the status bar. I would like to remove the full screen and make the app go from below so it is not hiding. On player settings on preferences the full screen / window mode did not make any difference.
Also adding fullscreen false to start() did not work. Any suggestions
Screen.fullScreen = false;

I followed the instructions given from here:
https://github.com/Over17/UnityShowAndroidStatusBar
I am using the manifest provided here.

Have you tried to change the options in the player settings?

Yes the setting does not affect in any way. I am using the 3.30f1 version unity

@JimMede there is no such version ... do you mean 2022.3.30f1?

@derHugo yes that version

this one should work https://gist.github.com/blevok/3dc5fec55a96b6f60ca24b49b4fcf98a
